# inconsistent thumbnail with ffmpeg on avi, mp4

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

i am getting inconsistent thumbanails when i add a new video. i have video files with width and height 640x480 and 1280x720. what do i have to change?

```
       public void exec(string input, string output, string parametri)
 {

        ffmpeg = new Process();

        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + input + (parametri != null ? " " + parametri : "") + " " + output;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        ffmpeg.Start();
        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
        ffmpeg.Close();
    }

    public void GetThumbnail(string video, string jpg, string velicina)
    {
        if (velicina == null) velicina = "640x480";
        exec(video, jpg, "-s " + velicina);
    }
    private void btnBrowseThumbnail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string newThumbnail = Properties.Settings.Default.folderPathUserThumbnail + "CopyFiles.jpg";
        GetThumbnail(txtFile.Text, newThumbnail, null);
        string curFile = newThumbnail;
        if (File.Exists(curFile))
            txtThumbnail.Text = newThumbnail;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i could only get thumbnail from certain video. When all the thumbnails are in avi format. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Thumbnails in AVI? Don't you want them as image files instead? I can't tell what's wrong with your code, but it would help if you could show us the actual ffmpeg commands that are being called (not how they're assembled), and what the full debug output is that ffmpeg gives you. You'd need to explain in which cases thumbnails are created and where it fails.